# Logitech USB headset not working on 12.04

Tags: usb, headset, logitech

I've looked around for answers to this question, But none of them seem to work for my particular problem. Obviously my USB headset isn't working, But I might as well share the scenario. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and I have a Logitech USB headset. The relevant output from `dmesg` is as follows:

```
[160708.528047] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 9

[160768.890123] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd

[160768.997578] input: Logitech Logitech USB Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.3/input/input15

[160768.997795] generic-usb 0003:046D:0A0C.0005: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Device [Logitech Logitech USB Headset] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input3
```

When I go to System Settings -> Sound, My headset shows up in both the Output and Input tabs, It is called "Clear Chat Comfort USB Headset" in those tabs, But I doubt that's a serious issue.

When I click my headset in either tab to use it, The changes are not remembered when I reopen the sound settings, the built-in audio is still used. Also when I select the headset in the Output tab, and click the Test Sound button to test everything, The sound still comes from my laptop's onboard audio, instead of from my USB headset.

Does anyone know how to correct this?  I am stumped.

Answer (score 9):

Finally the headset is usable now.
I just did an update recently, also additionally I've updated from the `ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y`

Now the usb headset is on the input and output tabs.
[image: input tab]

[image]

Comment: This worked great! Not sure why suddenly it was removed from the list as it was working about a month ago :/

One thing I noticed though is after a reboot having the USB Logitech device plugged in caused my machine to hang. It could have just been due to it needing to properly configure things -- not sure but now it's working after I rebooted without it attached.

Comment: This worked for me, had to restar after the update, but it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I opened system settings->sound. In that open Hardware  tab. It shows logitech USB headset.
Now click on Test Speakers, Front left, right. 
After this I able to get the audio from the headset.

Comment: My headset was working fine until I put the PC in standby. After resuming, it stopped working. Doing this fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be your problem, but I had similar trouble with a plantronics usb headset and found my solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/975941).

The steps for the fix are provided in comment #4 and comment #6, and reiterated handily in step #11.