# What is the proper way to configure my sound? [12.10]

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, equalizer

So I am using the Logitech G35 headset and it is USB. My sounds are much tinnier and just off compared to when I am on Windows. On Windows I do have access to the Logitech Gaming Software which allows me to adjust the different frequencies. I don't even have to touch the equalizer on Windows, just raise the bass/treble sliders up a little.

I installed `pulseaudio-equalizer` and it sounds horrible. If I raise the bass at all it gets terribly distorted. I noticed that `pulseaudio-equalizer` doesn't have a preamp, even though I've seen the preamp slider in old screenshots.

I've tried installing alsamixer but can't get past the `make install` part of the installation. I have the dependencies installed but I'm getting an error that `'/usr/lib/alsa-lib/' is not a directory`. I don't know what to do now so I've given up on that.

Surely there must be an easy way to configure my bass/treble without needing to do all this.

Comment: Sorrry, this isn't a right place to ask about elementary os. Only Ubuntu and [official ubuntu derivative](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives) questions are allowed. Questions on other derivatives are considered off topic. Please read [FAQ]

Comment: I have the same problem in Ubuntu. I can reinstall Ubuntu, ask this same question and it will be alright? Well I'll make a second partition and put Ubuntu on it and edit this post. Look the question now applies to Ubuntu. Please open the post again.

Comment: @Spaisekraft hi friend, can you add the Ubuntu version you are using. Have you also tried this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131812/logitech-usb-headset-not-working-on-12-04

Comment: @LuisAlvarado I'm using 12.10 right now. The headset is working fine. I see it in the sound panel for speakers and the microphone under input. Both work properly. I would just like to know if there is an easy straight forward way to change the frequencies. Thanks

Comment: @Spaisekraft did you try the link I mentioned. There is an answer of updated Sound libraries using a PPA.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado I will reboot into ubuntu right now and try that, although I don't see how that will help me adjust the frequencies for my audio.